# Асинхронные requests запросы

Tags: python, requests, request, асинхронность

Делаю для телеграмм бота requests запросы, чтобы не было задержки при отправлении сообщения бота пользователю, я использую асинхронность. У меня возникла проблема, что когда я запуская асинхронную функцию перебора данных пользователей, асинхронность работает, но вот с request запросами это не видно. Прошу помочь сделать так, чтобы асинхронность работала с requests запросами на телеграмм сервер.

Вот скрин, цифры это `id` пользователей, а response - это соответственно результата запроса:
[image: Скрин]

Вот Код:

```
import requests
import config
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from threading import *
from read_sql_config import read_db_config
import asyncio

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db_config = read_db_config()
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

def requests_message(user_id, id_telegram, wallet, name_wallet):
    print(user_id)
    res = requests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.api_token}/sendMessage?',
        params={
            'chat_id': user_id,
            'text': ("Тестовое сообщение")
        })
    print(res)

class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.iter = iter(seq)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

# Перебор полученных данных с БД
async def iter_row():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(300)
        if not rows:
            break
        async for row in AsyncIterator(rows):
            yield row 

# Запрос к БД на получение информации о пользователе
async def brute_force():
    while True:
        async for row in iter_row(): 
            if row[4] == 0:
                pass
            else:
                starting1 = Thread(target=requests_message, args=(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],))
                starting1.start()

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(brute_force())
loop.close()
```

Comment: requests по сути своей синхронная библиотека. Для выполнения запросов асинхронно используйте например aiohttp или httpx

Comment: Для mysql библиотека тоже синхронная, обратите внимание на aiomysql.

Comment: Если вы написали async функцию без единого await - что-то пошло в корне не так... Этот код проще переписать с нуля, разумеется, после того, как станет лучше понятно, как работает асинхронный код, event-loop в частности...